# Reuse nsdateformatter to display dates as strings

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I get tripped up on some simple things as I'm starting to learn to program.  If I use a NSDateFormatter in one of my ViewControllers to display the date I want in a certain format, and the format doesn't change, is it "best practices" to declare that NSDateFormatter as an ivar of my class or property of my class and initialize it in the viewDidLoad so I can reuse it in my different methods?  Right now I just instantiate one whenever I need it in a method that deals with the display and was wondering if it's better to just keep declaring it, or declare it once and just use it throughout the viewController class.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a "noob question"; it's a reasonable question with a reasonable answer.

From a pure efficiency standpoint, you're optimizing prematurely. Don't worry, be happy. If you're managing memory correctly (so that you're not leaking NSDateFormatters) it really shouldn't matter how you obtain a particular instance, especially given that this is such a lightweight object. If you're creating a new NSDateFormatter 1000 times in a loop, you're being silly, but if you're creating the object now and then when you need it and it's going back out of existence properly, it's no big deal.

On the other hand, from an architectural standpoint, make sure what you are doing is DRY. If the date formatter needs any configuration at all, don't repeat yourself each time you create it; write a method that supplies the date formatter the same way each time so that the configuration code is all in just one place.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating new objects always comes at the price of memory and computing time, so if it's possible without much effort you should try to declare it once and then reuse it, at least within the same class. `NSDateFormatter` is not thread-safe, though, so you can't simply share one instance between different threads.

Answer (score 0):

For any object, best practice is to just declare it at run time, use it and release it, so that the time taken by that object in memory remains maximum.

We make an ivar when we need the value of that ivar same throughout the class, like any age for an employee, it will be checked in different methods as in seniority, in ageWise category etc. And further if this iVar is an object, then in iPhone, it is a good practice always to be use it as property, so that the memory management problem shifts towards the compiler end.

Now in your case, you may generate a simple method that will take the date object and return the string, or any String as parameter and return date object, make an NSDateFormater there and use it. No need to make it as iVar.